# Sass - calculations with fractions possible?

Tags: css, sass

## Situation

I'm working on a fraction based grid sysem with calc() and flexbox.

I'm struggling to get sass to do calculations with fractions (e.g. "1/8").

Is this actually possible with sass?

---

#### Mixin

```
@mixin column($fraction: '1/1', $gutter: 20px) {
    width: calc(100% * #{$fraction} - (#{$gutter} - #{$gutter} * #{$fraction}));

    &:not(:nth-child(#{convert-fraction-to-full($fraction)}n) {
        margin-right: $gutter;
    }
}
```

#### Function

```
@function convert-fraction-to-full($fraction){
    @return #{$fraction} / #{$fraction} / #{$fraction};
}
```

---

#### Usage - Include

```
.griditem {
    @include column('1/8', 20px);
}
```

#### Usage - desired Output

```
.griditem {
    width: calc(100% * 1/8 - (20px - 20px * 1/8));
}
.griditem:not(:nth-child(8)) {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

---

## Problem

The width calculations work, because calc() is taking care of that. But the calculations inside the `:nth-child()` doesn't because sass cant handle fractions? Not sure, what's happening here?

## Code

Here's a pen to play around with:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxOyXq?editors=1100